# Pivot table content using awk command

Tags: awk

i would like to use awk to pivot the table content, can someone share how will i do this. thanks

table1

```
FEATURE,TESTER,LICENSE_USED,PROGRAM,AREA
Low,T6712,23,Element01,FT1
High,T7911,54,Element03,FT2
Medium,E8123,48,Element02,FT3
High,F4309,54,Element02,PB1
Low,F4309,23,Element01,PB1
Low,T7911,23,Element04,FT1
High,E8123,54,Element05,FT2
Medium,F4309,48,Element01,PB1
```

expected output, the Feature becomes column with the values from license used

```
TESTER,PROGRAM,AREA,High,Low,Medium
E8123,Element02,FT3,0,0,48
E8123,Element05,FT2,54,0,0
F4309,Element01,PB1,0,23,48
F4309,Element02,PB1,54,0,0
T6712,Element01,FT1,0,23,0
T7911,Element03,FT2,54,0,
T7911,Element04,FT1,0,23,0
```

another output, would it be possible transpose the expected output just like below?:

```
TESTER,E8123,E8123,F4309,F4309,T6712,T7911,T7911
PROGRAM,Element02,Element05,Element01,Element02,Element01,Element03,Element04
AREA,FT3,FT2,PB1,PB1,FT1,FT2,FT1
High,0,54,0,54,0,54,0
Low,0,0,23,0,23,0,23
Medium,48,0,48,0,0,,0
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the original input:

```
FEATURE,TESTER,LICENSE_USED,PROGRAM,AREA
Low,T6712,23,Element01,FT1
High,T7911,54,Element03,FT2
Medium,E8123,48,Element02,FT3
High,F4309,54,Element02,PB1
Low,F4309,23,Element01,PB1
Low,T7911,23,Element04,FT1
High,E8123,54,Element05,FT2
Medium,F4309,48,Element01,PB1
```

Let's pretty that up so we can see what's going on:

```
$ tr , '\011'  < data.txt | column -tR 3,5
FEATURE  TESTER  LICENSE_USED  PROGRAM    AREA
Low      T6712             23  Element01   FT1
High     T7911             54  Element03   FT2
Medium   E8123             48  Element02   FT3
High     F4309             54  Element02   PB1
Low      F4309             23  Element01   PB1
Low      T7911             23  Element04   FT1
High     E8123             54  Element05   FT2
Medium   F4309             48  Element01   PB1
```

Here's the expected output:

```
$ tr , '\011'  < expected.txt | column -tR 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
TESTER       E8123      E8123      F4309      F4309      T6712      T7911      T7911
PROGRAM  Element02  Element05  Element01  Element02  Element01  Element03  Element04
AREA           FT3        FT2        PB1        PB1        FT1        FT2        FT1
High             0         54          0         54          0         54          0
Low              0          0         23          0         23          0         23
Medium          48          0         48          0          0          0          0
```

It appears we want three column headers to be translated to row headers and we want to use Low, Medium, and High as row headers per tester/element/area (sorting by Tester makes this apparent):

```
$ tr , '\011'  < data.txt | column -tR 3 | sort -k2
Medium   E8123             48  Element02  FT3
High     E8123             54  Element05  FT2
Low      F4309             23  Element01  PB1
Medium   F4309             48  Element01  PB1
High     F4309             54  Element02  PB1
Low      T6712             23  Element01  FT1
Low      T7911             23  Element04  FT1
High     T7911             54  Element03  FT2
FEATURE  TESTER  LICENSE_USED  PROGRAM    AREA
```

We can easily see that Testers work on different Elements too, so we'll have to account for that:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
NR > 1 {
    data[$2,$4,$5] = data[$2,$4,$5] $1 ":" $3 FS
}
END {
    #construct the table
    for (tester_element_area in data) {
        split(tester_element_area, parts, SUBSEP)

        tester  = parts[1]
        element = parts[2]
        area    = parts[3]

        n = split(data[tester_element_area], d)

        template["High"]   = 0
        template["Medium"] = 0
        template["Low"]    = 0

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            split(d[i], license, ":")

            degree = license[1]
            value  = license[2]

            template[ degree ] = value
        }

        table["TESTER"]  = table["TESTER"]  FS tester
        table["PROGRAM"] = table["PROGRAM"] FS element
        table["AREA"]    = table["AREA"]    FS area
        table["High"]    = table["High"]    FS template["High"]
        table["Medium"]  = table["Medium"]  FS template["Medium"]
        table["Low"]     = table["Low"]     FS template["Low"]
    }

    #print the table
    header[1] = "TESTER"
    header[2] = "PROGRAM"
    header[3] = "AREA"
    header[4] = "High"
    header[5] = "Low"
    header[6] = "Medium"

    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        header_name = header[i]

        printf header_name

        n = split(table[header_name], parts)

        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (j > 1) {
                printf FS
            }
            printf parts[j]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Let's see what it returns:

```
$ awk -f prog.awk < data.txt | tr , '\011' | column -tR2,3,4,5,6,7,8
TESTER       E8123      T7911      F4309      E8123      T6712      T7911      F4309
PROGRAM  Element05  Element04  Element02  Element02  Element01  Element03  Element01
AREA           FT2        FT1        PB1        FT3        FT1        FT2        PB1
High            54          0         54          0          0         54          0
Low              0         23          0          0         23          0         23
Medium           0          0          0         48          0          0         48
```

Not too shabby, the columns aren't ordered exactly correct. They should be sorted. If you're willing to use GAWK, it requires a small code change:

```
END {
        for (tester_element_area in data) {                                     
                cols[++i] = tester_element_area                                 
        }                                                                       

        m = asort(cols)                                                         

        #construct the table                                                    
        for (k = 1; k <= m; k++) {                                              
                tester_element_area = cols[k]
                ...
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f prog.awk < data.txt | tr , '\011' | column -tR2,3,4,5,6,7,8
TESTER       E8123      E8123      F4309      F4309      T6712      T7911      T7911
PROGRAM  Element02  Element05  Element01  Element02  Element01  Element03  Element04
AREA           FT3        FT2        PB1        PB1        FT1        FT2        FT1
High             0         54          0         54          0         54          0
Low              0          0         23          0         23          0         23
Medium          48          0         48          0          0          0          0
```

**Update: Sort by Area**

```
NR > 1 {
    data[$5,$2,$4] = data[$5,$2,$4] $1 ":" $3 FS
}
END {
        for (tester_element_area in data) {                                     
                cols[++i] = tester_element_area
        }                                                                       

        m = asort(cols)                                                         

        #construct the table                                                    
        for (k = 1; k <= m; k++) {                                              
                tester_element_area = cols[k]
                split(tester_element_area, parts, SUBSEP)

                area     = parts[1]
                tester   = parts[2]
                element  = parts[3]
```

Output:

```
TESTER       T6712      T7911      E8123      T7911      E8123      F4309      F4309
PROGRAM  Element01  Element04  Element05  Element03  Element02  Element01  Element02
AREA           FT1        FT1        FT2        FT2        FT3        PB1        PB1
High             0          0         54         54          0          0         54
Low             23         23          0          0          0         23          0
Medium           0          0          0          0         48         48          0
```

Comment: how to sort it by AREA?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN {
    # set input, output and subscript separator to comma
    FS = OFS = SUBSEP = ","
  }

  NR > 1 {
    # keep test-program-area in `a` for future reference
    a[$2, $4, $5] 
    # associate license_used with test-program-area-(high/low/medium) in `b`
    b[$2, $4, $5, $1] = $3
  }

  END {
    print "TESTER", "PROGRAM", "AREA", "High", "Low", "Medium"
    # for each key in `a`
    for (k in a)
      # print (test, program, area), high, low, medium
      print k, int(b[k, "High"]), int(b[k, "Low"]), int(b[k, "Medium"])
  }
' file
TESTER,PROGRAM,AREA,High,Low,Medium
F4309,Element02,PB1,54,0,0
E8123,Element02,FT3,0,48,0
T6712,Element01,FT1,0,0,23
T7911,Element03,FT2,54,0,0
F4309,Element01,PB1,0,48,23
E8123,Element05,FT2,54,0,0
T7911,Element04,FT1,0,0,23
```

Without spaces and comments if you're looking for a fancy one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","} NR>1{a[$2,$4,$5];b[$2,$4,$5,$1]=$3} END{print "TESTER","PROGRAM","AREA","High","Low","Medium";for(c in a) print k,0+b[k,"High"],0+b[k,"Low"],0+b[k,"Medium"]}' file
```

---

For a transposed output:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ","
  tr[cell[4, 1] = "High"  ] = 4
  tr[cell[5, 1] = "Low"   ] = 5
  tr[cell[6, 1] = "Medium"] = 6
}
{
  cell[1, NR] = $2
  cell[2, NR] = $4
  cell[3, NR] = $5
}
NR > 1 {
  cell[tr[$1], NR] = $3
}
END {
  for (row = 1; row <= 6; ++row) {
    for (col = 1; col <= NR; ++col)
      if (row > 3 && col > 1)
        $col = int(cell[row, col])
      else
        $col = cell[row, col]
    print
  }
}' file
TESTER,T6712,T7911,E8123,F4309,F4309,T7911,E8123,F4309
PROGRAM,Element01,Element03,Element02,Element02,Element01,Element04,Element05,Element01
AREA,FT1,FT2,FT3,PB1,PB1,FT1,FT2,PB1
High,0,54,0,54,0,0,54,0
Low,23,0,0,0,23,23,0,0
Medium,0,0,48,0,0,0,0,48
```

To sort it by `AREA` (i.e **5th** column):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ","
  tr[cell[4, 1] = "High"  ] = 4
  tr[cell[5, 1] = "Low"   ] = 5
  tr[cell[6, 1] = "Medium"] = 6
}
{
  cell[1, NR] = $2
  cell[2, NR] = $4
  cell[3, NR] = $5
}
NR > 1 {
  cell[tr[$1], NR] = $3
}
END {
  for (row = 1; row <= 6; ++row) {
    for (col = 1; col <= NR; ++col)
      if (row > 3 && col > 1)
        $col = int(cell[row, col])
      else
        $col = cell[row, col]
    print
  }
}' <(head -n 1 file) <(tail -n +2 file | sort -t ',' -k 5) # <- 5th
TESTER,T6712,T7911,E8123,T7911,E8123,F4309,F4309,F4309
PROGRAM,Element01,Element04,Element05,Element03,Element02,Element02,Element01,Element01
AREA,FT1,FT1,FT2,FT2,FT3,PB1,PB1,PB1
High,0,0,54,54,0,54,0,0
Low,23,23,0,0,0,0,23,0
Medium,0,0,0,0,48,0,0,48
```

**Note**: if you're using a different shell than bash and can't get the last one to work, ditch process substitution and use a command group, like:

```
{ head -n 1 file; tail -n +2 file | sort -t ',' -k 5; } | awk '...'
```

Comment: Hi, would it be possible to transpose the expected output?

Comment: okay, i posted it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862751/transpose-columns-of-data-table-using-awk