# Transpose columns of data table using awk

Tags: awk

This is a follow thru with regards to my previous question: ([Pivot table content using awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821891/pivot-table-content-using-awk-command)), i wanted to transpose the data. see the expected output

in below code(from oguz):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","} NR>1{a[$2,$4,$5];b[$2,$4,$5,$1]=$3} END{print "TESTER","PROGRAM","AREA","High","Low","Medium";for(c in a) print c,0+b[c,"High"],0+b[c,"Low"],0+b[c,"Medium"]}' file
```

the output is below:

```
TESTER,PROGRAM,AREA,High,Low,Medium
F4309,Element02,PB1,54,0,0
E8123,Element02,FT3,0,48,0
T6712,Element01,FT1,0,0,23
T7911,Element03,FT2,54,0,0
F4309,Element01,PB1,0,48,23
E8123,Element05,FT2,54,0,0
T7911,Element04,FT1,0,0,23
```

i wanted to tranpose it like below:

```
TESTER,E8123,E8123,F4309,F4309,T6712,T7911,T7911
PROGRAM,Element02,Element05,Element01,Element02,Element01,Element03,Element04
AREA,FT3,FT2,PB1,PB1,FT1,FT2,FT1
High,0,54,0,54,0,54,0
Low,0,0,23,0,23,0,23
Medium,48,0,48,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume you want to transpose AND sort?